# Why does the inverse of a positive matrix make negative values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, inverse

I've been working with matrices in python recently, and when I use `np.linalg.pinv(matrix)` I get negative values even though all the values in `matrix` are positive. For example,

```
matrix = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print(np.linalg.pinv(matrix))
```

outputs

```
[[-6.38888889e-01 -1.66666667e-01  3.05555556e-01]
 [-5.55555556e-02  3.36727575e-17  5.55555556e-02]
 [ 5.27777778e-01  1.66666667e-01 -1.94444444e-01]]
```

Why would the sign change if it's just an inverse?

Comment: You can get negatives when inversing. Test if it is the inverse by multiplying it with your original matrix, then you should get the identity matrix if it is correct.

Comment: I just tried `np.dot(test, np.linalg.pinv(test))` but I didn't get the identity matrix

Comment: The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html) describes which equalities are maintained (see "Examples" section). For some mathematical background, see [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse)

Comment: @Timmy Looking at [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html), you want `np.dot(matrix, np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(matrix), matrix))`. (Though personally I don't know what that means.)

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought of (or seen) that

Comment: @TimmyDiehl: `np.dot(matrix, np.linalg.pinv(matrix))` can't possibly return the identity matrix, because the `matrix` that you chose is not invertible (as is easily checked by computing its determinant).